# Mongoose query altering object order

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a query that is generated in my Node backend - if I log it out and run it in Mongo shell then all is fine, however, if I use mongoose to do `Model.find(query)`, then some strange property re-ordering takes place and the query breaks.

The query in question is:

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "$all": [
            {
                "attribute": "an id",
                "value": "a value",
                "deletedOn": null
            },
            {
                "attribute": "an id again",
                "value": "a value",
                "deletedOn": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

However, the output from mongoose debug is:

```
users.find({ 
    attributes: { 
        '$all': [ 
            { 
                deletedOn: null,
                attribute: 'an id',
                value: 'a value'
            },
            {
                deletedOn: null,
                attribute: 'an id again',
                value: 'a value'
            }
        ]
    } 
},
    { fields: {} }
)
```

The only change is the shifting of the `deletedOn` field from last position to first position in the object.  This means the query returns no results.

Are there any solutions to this issue?

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#retainKeyOrder (although I'm not sure if that will work on `$all`).

Comment: "The retainKeyOrder option was removed, mongoose will now always retain the same key position when cloning objects. If you have queries or indexes that rely on reverse key order, you will have to change them."

[mongoosejs migrating to 5.x - retain-key-order](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_5.html#retain-key-order)

Answer (score 0):

Object properties in JavaScript are **not ordered**. You cannot ensure the order of properties on a JavaScript object and different implementations may order them differently. See [this answer on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/1985406) for some other info.

The essential key is that from the spec (ECMAScript) we get: "An object is a member of the type Object. **It is an unordered collection of properties** each of which contains a primitive value, object, or function. A function stored in a property of an object is called a method."

There is no "solution", because this is expected behavior. So the real question is, why does the order matter to you? What are you trying to do?

Comment: The order matters because when querying MongoDB { a: 1, b: 2 } is not equal to { b: 2. a: 1 } - mongo uses BSON instead of JSON where property order is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on the previous answer, if order is important to you, you should use array instead of objects.

for example:

```
"$all": [
    [
        {"attribute": "an id"},
        {"value": "a value"},
        {"deletedOn": null},
    ],
    ...etc.
]
```